# This query used to work fine, now it fails. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql, azure

I am not super strong at SQL, so I apologize ahead of time. I have the following query that used to work without issue:

```
 select A.arcNumber,
            A.arcName,
            A.arcContact,
            B.easEmailAddress,
            E.asrcode,
            A.arcARSalesRepID,
            A.arcOpenOrderAmt,
            C.lkpCaption AS EmailLookup,
            D.lkpCaption AS CustomerType
 from   orman.dbo.tblARCustomer A
            INNER JOIN  orman.dbo.tblEmailAddress B
                    ON  A.arcID = B.easEntityId 
                    AND B.easEntityType = 'C'
            INNER JOIN  orman.dbo.tblLookup C
                    On  C.lkpID = B.easEmailTypeLookupID
                    AND C.lkpCaption = 'GENERAL'
            INNER JOIN  orman.dbo.tblLookup D
                    On  A.arcCustomerSourceLookupID = D.lkpID
            INNER JOIN  orman.dbo.tblARSalesREp E
                    ON  A.arcARSalesRepID = E.asrCode
 where A.arcIsActive = 1
```

Now I am receiving the following error when trying to execute:

```
Started executing query at Line 1
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.' to data type int.
Total execution time: 00:00:00.011
```

What happened that caused it to throw this error and how can I resolve this? Thank you ahead of time for any responses.

Comment: Could you add the create table and/or column data types and some sample data

Comment: The VARCHAR (String) conversion to an Integer failed(Number) .. because the string is a SINGLE PERIOD.  So either a column somehow has a period in it .. doubtful if the database column only stores INT .. so instead one of them is empty/null likely so when it tries to convert a period into a number, its like .. yeah .. sorry i can't do that dave.

Comment: Even if it was working, the query was silently casting values (converting string values to numbers) to perform comparisons. Now the table has bad data and, of course, the query fails.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can tell which column is throwing the "NOTHING" at you, but what you could do, is do a test like to see if its NULL and then also if it is EMPTY and if either of those cases happen, set the value to 0 .. that way it is at least an integer so the record will try to pull and the missing data from that pull gives you an idea of which column to look at to find out what happened.

Comment: Does Microsoft Workbench work with Azure ?  I would HOPE so .. if it does .. you might play around with that to help you look at the tables easier and see whats going on .. turns DB operation into EXCEL level difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.' to data type int.` to occur is that there is an attempt made to convert a character that is not numeric into `int` type. Try using the following steps to overcome this error.

- Inspect the data in your tables, there might be a column which is of `varchar` type and consists of incorrect numeric values. So, the conversion fails, and it gives you an error
- When joining on the condition, try casting the column to int using `TRY_CAST` function. This function converts the current datatype to required datatype. If the conversion is unsuccessful for any reason (as in your case), the function returns `NULL`.

This should help in avoiding the error. Please refer to this [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/80800/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-valu.html) which addresses the similar issue. Also refer to this following link to understand about `TRY_CAST` method.

[TRY_CAST (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)